# Ansible-galaxy throws ImportError: No module named yaml

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-galaxy

When I try to install ansible role, I see this exception.

```
 $ ansible-galaxy install zzet.postgresql
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/myHomeDir/.homebrew/Cellar/ansible/1.4.3/libexec/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 34, in <module>
 import yaml
 ImportError: No module named yaml
```

OS: Mac Os Maverick
Ansible: 1.4.3

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Based on the error message, it tries to import the python module `yaml` but cannot find it. The yaml module is called `pyyaml` when you install it with `pip`:

`pip install pyyaml`

If `pip` is not installed on your mac then you can install it as,

`easy_install pip`

Comment: Thx! It's help me: pip install pyyaml

Comment: This annoys me. Why call it pyyaml in pip and yaml when importing? I'm not much of a python dev but it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 13):

For me `pip install yaml` doesn’t work in Mavericks.

`pip install pyyaml` works

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `pip install yaml` answer, and it didn't work for me. I had to reinstall ansible in order for the command line to catch. IE,

**failing**

```
ansible-galaxy install bcen01.nodejs                          [43m] ✭
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/1.4.3/libexec/bin/ansible-galaxy", line 34, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

**reinstall**

```
brew reinstall ansible
```

**success**

```
ansible-galaxy install bcen01.nodejs                          [43m] ✭
 no version specified, installing master
 - downloading role from https://github.com/bcen/ansible-nodejs/archive/master.tar.gz
 - extracting bcen01.nodejs to /usr/local/etc/ansible/roles/bcen01.nodejs
bcen01.nodejs was installed successfully
```

Comment: I tried to uninstall and reinstall ansible, and it didn't work for me. But may be it was bug fix and now all works?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with

sudo python -m easy_install pyyaml

The problem isn't in pyyaml, its in your version of setuptools. See  http://codyaray.com/2011/12/pyyaml-using-easy_install-on-mac-os-x-lion for references

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands to install latest yaml-

wget http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz

tar -xvzf PyYAML-3.12.tar.gz

cd PyYAML-3.12

python setup.py install

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Sep 21 2017, 21:46:26)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    >>> import yaml
    >>>
```